# How to implement Random Decision Forest classification in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, random-forest, data-analysis

I am making an iOS application using objective-c and Xcode that will collect and analyze some data from the user. Using this data, it will return one of 3 classifications. I can use training data in either R or Python to create a random forest model that has the capability to do this. I would like to know now I can implement this model in the iOS  application so that it can return a classification. If this is not possible, then maybe it is possible to synthesize the model in the application itself and somehow store it for use again with new data, or use stored training data to make a new model every time if it is not possible to store the model in the application itself.

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using [BigML](http://bigml.com), a cloud-based ML service that also provides a [REST API](https://bigml.com/developers/) plus [Swift](https://github.com/bigmlcom/bigml-swift) and [ObjC SDKs](https://github.com/bigmlcom/ml4ios).

BigML provides support for many ML algorithms, including decision trees, clusters, anomaly detectectors, and, most importantly in your case, [ensembles](http://blog.bigml.com/2013/04/29/1-click-random-decision-forests/).

One interesting feature that both the ObjC and Swift SDKs provide is local predictions for any of the aforementioned ML algorithms. In other terms, you can create your model/cluster/ensemble through using the Web UI, then, once you are satisfied with the results, you can download it, put it into your app's bundle and load it into BigML's SDK to generate predictions offline -- i.e. without using the remote service. Of course, the SDKs also support creating your ML resources directly (that is, without going through the Web UI), if your requirement is generating, e.g., a model from user data.

An example of how you can retrieve an ensemble (forest tree) from BigML and use it to make a prediction is this:

```
ML4iOS* ml4iOS = [[ML4iOS alloc] initWithUsername:_BML_USERNAME
       key:_BML_APIKEY
       developmentMode:YES]];

NSDictionary* inputData = @{
    @"sepal width": @4.1,
    @"petal length": @0.96,
    @"petal width": @2.52};

NSInteger httpStatusCode = 0;
NSDictionary* ensemble = [self getEnsembleWithIdSync:ensembleId
    statusCode:&httpStatusCode];

NSDictionary* prediction =
    [ML4iOSLocalPredictions localPredictionWithJSONEnsembleSync:ensemble
       arguments:inputData
       options:@{ @"byName" : @(YES) }
       ml4ios:ml4iOS];
```

Full disclosure: I am currently working at BigML.

Comment: Thank you for  your response! I have looked into BigML and, while it does seem  promising, I am unable to find extensive documentation on how to implement it into IOS. The Github project "BigML4ios", is cited on your website.  However, the project itself doesn't provide much explanation ad instruction on  usage.  I would appreciate it  if you could guide me further, thank  you

Comment: Would you mind explaining better what you have tried and what you are trying to do, in more concrete terms? If we keep this discussion on S.O., this might benefit other people, too, so I think it might be worth to do it here; otherwise, feel free to reach me at desimone at bigml dot com. Anyway, I have added a short example to my answer.